# RAML: how to export only particular type of XSD

Tags: mule, raml

I'm writing a RAML where response is an XML that corresponds to one particular type among many other types defined in an external XSD. 
Is there a way to specify the particular type name from the XSD when defining parameter in RAML? 
I.e. now I define it something like this:

```
   responses: 
      200:
        body:
          application/xml: 
              schema: !include schemas/ManyManyTypesInside.xsd
```

But I would like to specify a particular type defined in the xsd to be used as a response type.

Note, that I don't wanna extract the type to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on the question depends on the RAML version.

Version 0.8 does not support referring to inner elements of XML Schema.

This feature has been added in RAML v1.0 and the format is like this:

```
schema: !include elements.xsd#Foo
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with RAML without separating the XSD portion into it's own XSD.

Why can't you separate it for just documentation/RAML purposes?

Comment: Because it's convenient to keep all the info in one schema document. XSD allows this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree is not in the spec, but you can do exactly that with the RAML Tools for .Net

In the response schema you specify the name of the type.

See https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-dotnet-tools#xml-schemas

Comment: This is interesting. The Anypoint RAML editor generates an error for the RAML from the link: "Description Resource Path Location Type
invalid XML schema (PurchaseOrderType): Content is not allowed in prolog. test.raml /order_tracker/src/main/resources line 140 RAML Problems
"